# Acronym: show only the long version and only once with the citation and/or footnote

Tags: citing, acronyms, acro

I think I've a use case / misuse hat is not yet covered by the nice acro package: I want to manage default citations and footnotes for some words - so not really acronyms in this case. A short MWE below.

Expected is something like: "This is \acx*{Metacomputing} and with \acx*{Metacomputing} we can do stuff" --> "This is Metacomputing[1]^1 and with Metacomputing we can do stuff" (without an entry in the acronym list).

I switched from the acronym package and used there the \aclu*{Metacomputing} command. Any idea how to simulate this behavior with the acro package?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@article{Smar1992,
author = {Smarr, Larry and Catlett, Charles E},
journal = {Communications of the ACM},
number = {6},
pages = {44--52},
publisher = {ACM},
title = {{Metacomputing}},
volume = {35},
year = {1992}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\acsetup{single,sort}

\DeclareAcronym{Metacomputing}{short={Metacomputing}, long={Metacomputing}, cite={Smar1992}, long-post={\protect\footnote{\url{http://example.org}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Expected: Metacomputing[1]; Metacomputing.
  \item Instead:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item ac: \ac{Metacomputing}; \ac{Metacomputing}. \acresetall
      \item ac*: \ac*{Metacomputing}; \ac*{Metacomputing}. \acresetall
      \item acflike: \acflike{Metacomputing}{}; \acflike{Metacomputing}{}. \acresetall
      \item acs: \acs{Metacomputing}; \acs*{Metacomputing}{}. \acresetall
      \item acl: \acl{Metacomputing}; \acl*{Metacomputing}{}. \acresetall
      \item acf: \acf{Metacomputing}; \acf*{Metacomputing}{}. \acresetall
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\printacronyms
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Best regards, Alex

Comment: I'll have a look at this at the weekend. (Did you ask the same/a simular thing on acro's bitbucket site?)

Comment: Nice, thanks. No, but via mail. But I thought this question might bring an added value to this community.

Comment: It would be rather easy to add commands `\Aclc`/`\aclc` which would be long forms that also add a citation if one is defined for the acronym. `acro`'s `class` option would allow to exclude certain acronyms from the list.

Comment: Sounds good. I assume this includes also the footnote and the possibility to hide it from the list of acronyms? Further, spelling out the acronym without any footnote or citation can come handy (e.g. to use it in section headers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a command `\aclu`, say, which exactly does what you want:

> Expected is something like:
>
> ```
> This is \acx*{Metacomputing} and with \acx*{Metacomputing} we can do stuff
> ```
>
> > This is Metacomputing[1]^1 and with Metacomputing we can do stuff
>
> (without an entry in the acronym list).

**Update 2015/08/26**: with v2.0 or greater

The following defines a new conditional switch which is set to true if the acronym is used for the first time. This can be used to insert the footnote depending on the value of the switch. This is necessary because `\acifused` always gives false inside of the acronym properties.

```
\newif\ifacrousefootnote
\newcommand\acfootnote[1]{\ifacrousefootnote\footnote{#1}\fi}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewAcroCommand \aclu
  {
    \acro_is_used:nF {#1}
      { \acrousefootnotetrue \acro_cite: }
    \acro_long:n {#1}
  }
\NewAcroCommand \Aclu
  {
    \acro_if_acronym_used:nF {#1}
      { \acrousefootnotetrue \acro_cite: }
    \acro_first_upper:
    \acro_long:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Another possible definition would be the following:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \aclu {sm}
  {
    \acro_begin:
      \acro_reset_specials:
      \acro_check_acronym:nn {#2} {false}
      \acro_if_acronym_used:nF {#2} { \acro_cite: }
      \acro_long:n {#2}
      \IfBooleanF #1 { \acro_mark_as_used:n {#2} }
    \acro_end:
  }
% upper case version:
\NewDocumentCommand \Aclu {sm}
  {
    \acro_begin:
      \acro_reset_specials:
      \acro_check_acronym:nn {#2} {false}
      \acro_first_upper:
      \acro_if_acronym_used:nF {#2} { \acro_cite: }
      \acro_long:n {#2}
      \IfBooleanF #1 { \acro_mark_as_used:n {#2} }
    \acro_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

With this `\acifused` actually *can* be used in the properties of an acronym.

If you also add a class to the acronym definition you can exclude it later from the list of printed acronyms. Full example that uses the first version of the macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

% for demonstration purposes only: make the page small!
\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Smar1992,
  author    = {Smarr, Larry and Catlett, Charles E},
  journal   = {Communications of the ACM},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {44--52},
  publisher = {ACM},
  title     = {Metacomputing},
  volume    = {35},
  year      = {1992}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{acro}[2015-04-08]
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\acsetup{single,sort}

% make \footnote and \url robust commands, needs package `etoolbox':
\robustify\footnote
\robustify\url

\newif\ifacrousefootnote
\newcommand\acfootnote[1]{\ifacrousefootnote\footnote{#1}\fi}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewAcroCommand \aclu
  {
    \acro_is_used:nF {#1}
      { \acrousefootnotetrue \acro_cite: }
    \acro_long:n {#1}
  }
\NewAcroCommand \Aclu
  {
    \acro_if_acronym_used:nF {#1}
      { \acrousefootnotetrue \acro_cite: }
    \acro_first_upper:
    \acro_long:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{Metacomputing}{
  short     = {metacomputing} ,
  long      = {metacomputing} ,
  cite      = {Smar1992} ,
  long-post = {\acfootnote{\url{http://example.org}}} ,
  class     = exclude
}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short     = {foo} ,
  long      = {foo bar baz}
}

\begin{document}

\Ac{foo} and later \ac{foo}.

\Aclu{Metacomputing} and later \aclu{Metacomputing}.

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=exclude]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

With version 1.6a of `acro`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% for demonstration purposes only: make the page small!
\usepackage[paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@article{Smar1992,
  author    = {Smarr, Larry and Catlett, Charles E},
  journal   = {Communications of the ACM},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {44--52},
  publisher = {ACM},
  title     = {Metacomputing},
  volume    = {35},
  year      = {1992}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{acro}[2015-04-08]
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\acsetup{single,sort}

% make \footnote and \url robust commands, needs package `etoolbox':
\robustify\footnote
\robustify\url

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \aclu {sm}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \acro_check_acronym:nn {#2} {false}
      \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {#2} {} { \acro_cite: }
      \acro_long:n {#2}
      \IfBooleanF #1 { \acro_mark_as_used:n {#2} }
    \group_end:
  }
% upper case version:
\NewDocumentCommand \Aclu {sm}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \acro_check_acronym:nn {#2} {false}
      \acro_upper:
      \acro_if_acronym_used:nTF {#2} {} { \acro_cite: }
      \acro_long:n {#2}
      \IfBooleanF #1 { \acro_mark_as_used:n {#2} }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareAcronym{Metacomputing}{
  short     = {metacomputing} ,
  long      = {metacomputing} ,
  cite      = {Smar1992} ,
  long-post = {\acifused{Metacomputing}{}{\footnote{\url{http://example.org}}}} ,
  class     = exclude
}

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{
  short     = {foo} ,
  long      = {foo bar baz}
}

\begin{document}

\Ac{foo} and later \ac{foo}.

\Aclu{Metacomputing} and later \aclu{Metacomputing}.

\printacronyms[exclude-classes=exclude]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Splendid. Tested it in a larger document and at first sight it seems to work as expected. You might want to add such a command natively without the need to define it first.

Comment: Addendum: I'm looking for somethings like \acclean{short} that behaves exactly like \ac but omits the "cite" and "long-post" annotations. An idea?

Comment: @Alex it is quite doable to omit the citation but it is impossible to omit `long-pre`

Comment: I'm coming back to this. In the MWE using a simple ```\ac``` command does not show a footnote in case the acronym ```foo``` would have a ```long-post``` defined, analog to the ```Metacomputing``` acronym.